# USB stick does not appear automatically in the launcher when entry is given in fstab for noexec option

Tags: 12.04, fstab

We tried to mount usb for a limited user, which is not a sudo user.

When we give auto mounting, the permissions shown when issuing the mount command are:

```
nosuid,rw,nodev
```

But we want to give `noexec` option also while mounting a USB stick by the user. So in the `fstab` we gave the line:

```
/dev/sdb1  /mnt/usb auto auto,nodev,noexec,nosuid,user,rw 0 2
```

The USB hard drive does not get automatically mounted and icon doesn't appear in the launcher also. It can only mount with command `mount /mnt/usb`.

How to automatically mount usb to view it in the launcher for the limited user with `noexec` option additionally set?

Thanks..

Comment: Having the `user` option already adds `nodev,noexec,nosuid`. Have you tried executing a binary from the USB stick to make sure that you really need to add `noexec`?